# Remove thing from my array if they don't have a prefix

Tags: javascript

This is my first question here, so please be nice :)

I have an array with different names in it. This looks like that: `["student:Monica", "student:Rebecca", "student:James", "teacher:Mr. Anders"]`.
In reality there are more names in there. From this, I want to make a list with only the students and it shouldn't say `student:` in front of it.

So I tried to do it like that:

```
var students_and_teachers = ["student:Monica", "student:Rebecca", "student:James", "teacher:Mr. Anders"];

for (i = 0; i < students_and_teachers.length; i++) {
  var a_student_or_teacher = students_and_teachers[i];
  if (a_student_or_teacher.startsWith("student:") === true) {
    students_and_teachers[i] = a_student_or_teacher.substring(8, 100);
  } else {
    delete students_and_teachers[i];
  }
}
```

And this works good but now when I show the students and teachers afterwards it looks like that: `Array [ "Monica", "Rebecca", "James", ,  ]` . But it should only have the three students and not the empty things in the end.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh. OK. I'm sorry :((

Comment: @Chloe_C No worries, if your question gets closed as duplicate this is fine. Actually, your question is quite good for a first-question-on-SO as you have a clear problem description and show your actual code. Keep this up and you are fine. Searching for this duplicate is not an easy task for a beginner, but will get easier over time - So seeing that you are 16 I'd like to encourage you to learn programming.

Answer (score 0):

How about that ?

```
students_and_teachers.map(function( name ) {
  name = name.split( ':' );
  return name[ 0 ] === 'student' ? name[ 1 ] : '';
}).filter( Boolean );
```

Reference: [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&ei=hfflVLjgOMOyUYbJgtAG&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=6m2742mPje7xRlx2WynAGA&bvm=bv.85970519,d.d24), [`String.prototype.split`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit&ei=mvflVOflCsf5UpiSgbAC&usg=AFQjCNGVGuY9DfI9VAkeEZ1pZRBFS8cyUg&sig2=ISfj6VQRRFc5ldhONflzMw&bvm=bv.85970519,d.d24)

Comment: Cool :)) I want to be able to do that so fast too!! :)) Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Filter for students and then remove ":" try

```
students_and_teachers.filter(function( name ) {
  return name.indexOf("student") > -1;
}).map(function( name ) {
  return name.split( ':' )[ 1 ];
});
```

Result will be something like

```
 Array [ "Monica", "Rebecca", "James" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are great alternatives posted, but the reason your code doesn't work is because `delete` doesn't remove an array element – it simply leaves it as undefined.

You can remove array elements by using [**`splice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Once you've removed the element, you need to decrement the loop variable (`i--`).  Otherwise, it will skip over the next element.

My **snippet** uses [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) , because most browsers don't yet support 
[**`startsWith`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
var students_and_teachers = [
  "student:Monica", 
  "student:Rebecca", 
  "student:James", 
  "teacher:Mr. Anders",
  "teacher:Ms. Jones",
  "student:Rick"
];

for (i = 0; i < students_and_teachers.length; i++) {
  var a_student_or_teacher = students_and_teachers[i];
  if (a_student_or_teacher.indexOf("student:") === 0) {
    students_and_teachers[i] = a_student_or_teacher.substring(8, 100);
  } else {
    students_and_teachers.splice(i,1);
    i--;
  }
}

alert(students_and_teachers);
```